# Install Mail Plugin - says that install-plugin is deprecated

Tags: grails

I got this warning when i tried to install the mail plugin.

```
Loading Grails 2.2.4
| Environment set to development.....
| Warning The install-plugin command is deprecated and may be removed from a future version of Grails.  Plugin dependencies should be expressed in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy.  See http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/conf.html#pluginDependencies.
| Resolving plugin mail. Please wait...
```

The command i used was `install-plugin mail`. When i checked the [documentation](http://grails.org/plugin/mail) it as well shows me the same command.

Can someone direct me by telling me what the correct command is?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run any command, just declare the plugin dependency in `BuildConfig.groovy` like so:

```
plugins {
  runtime ":mail:1.0.4"
}
```

Remove any reference to the plugin that may exist in `application.properties`.